# Powershell script error, email script - error

Tags: html, powershell, shell, cmd

I am keep getting errors from my Power Shell code, everytime I try run it it says

```
At C:\Users\thoma\Documents\soubor.ps1:11 char:26
+ $Server = "smtp.gmail.com"
+                          ~
The string is missing the terminator: ".
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString
```

Full code is here:

```
$login = "andrew.spmr01@gmail.com"
$heslo = "MyPassword"
$To = "mek@mailinator.com"
$Copy = "andrew.spmr01@gmail.com"
$Attachment = "test"
$Subject = "Photos of Drogon"
$Body = "<br>Please see attached picture for reference."
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
$heslo = ConvertTo-SecureString "heslo" -AsPlainText –Force
$SMTPPort = "587"
$autentizace = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($login, $heslo)
$Server = "smtp.gmail.com"

Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Cc $Copy -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $Server -Port $SMTPPort -UseSsl -Credential $autentizace -Attachments $Attachment
```

Please is here someone who can tell me how should i fix in this code?

Comment: Not reproduced. How do you run it?

Comment: You can run it by saving it in .ps1 file and run with windows power shell

Comment: The error message shows a line of code that **doesn't exist in the code you've posted below**. Please post the exact code

Comment: Now everything should be good, posted wrong error message before

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that PowerShell thinks the `"` at the end of `smtp.gmail.com"` is the beginning of a string which doesn't have a close-quote later in the command. So either you're missing the one at the beginning of it, or you have an extra one earlier in the line; basically, you have an odd number of quotation marks in the command.

The code you posted does not display the problem. Are you sure that's the whole file?

I note that you assign a variable called `$SMTPServer` but then use the variable called simply `$Server` on the `Send-MailMessage` call... and the error refers to an assignment to `$Server` which is not present in the code here. So clearly the code you posted is not the same code you're running.

Comment: yes, but I do not have extra " anywhere

Comment: Not even inside the password value, which you presumably changed before posting?